# Monstera yellowing despite proper watering and no apparent sickness

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, bugs, monstera

I've had this *Monstera* for about two years now and I've never has this problem, I'm careful not to over/under water, it's thrived until now so I suspect sunlight is not the issue either.

I've recently had a friend's *Monstera* over because hers was way over watered and she wanted me to try and save it. I couldn't but mine is now starting to exhibit similar symptoms, with yellowing leaves and sort of blurry patches developing on the leaves which leads me to think it might be disease related.

At first I figured it might just be that one leaf but it's now starting to spread and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've read up quite a bit online as to what it might be and I've ruled out the most common ones that are usually linked to either over/under watering as well as those that spread from plant wounds. I've checked for spider mite webs but couldn't seem to find any.

It seem to affect leaf tissue most since some leaves still have rather green veins that can be seen despite the leaf turning yellow.

[image: First sick leaf, now removed]

[image: Second sick leaf, still shows green veins]

Can anyone point me to what might be affecting my *Monstera* so I might try and save it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't always see webs. Some spider mites are nearly microscopic. But inexorable yellowing after a visiting plants sounds exactly like spider mites. Wash the plant twice per week, every millimeter of every part of the plant with a strong stream of water. Do this for a few weeks, and you should get rid of them. Still, be sure to isolate it for a least 3-4 months!

Comment: Soap and water works even better